# Hot Network Questions shouldn't include per-site metas

Tags: bug, hot-questions

Today the Hot Network Questions list includes questions from several per-site metas:

- [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380600/2019-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) (in case the election needed more visibility?)
- [Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/are-history-of-worldbuilding-questions-on-topic) (not especially hot, even)
- [Workplace Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5995/325)
- [Math Meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/cool-project-ideas)

(Maybe more; I didn't review all 100.)

Most hot site issues are hot *site* issues and don't benefit from broader exposure.  I trust this is a bug and not intended behavior?

Comment: Personally, I'd be interested in seeing a collection of the hottest site Meta issues across the network.

Comment: @Alex I would too, but I think we'd all agree that that's very much an "SE insider" thing that shouldn't be sprung on unsuspecting SO users. :-)

Comment: Indeed, we wouldn't want that.

Comment: As this post is clearly a duplicate, posted only *one* minute later than the "original", and the issue/bug was immediately resolved–the fix was implemented within 15 minutes–what are the chances of this question being useful to future visitors? Wouldn't the proper thing be to delete it? There are no answers posted, so the system allows this course of action.  P.S I haven't voted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA most people will never see it once it's off the front page today or tomorrow; it can join the (tens of?) thousands of other such questions here.